# Hive: handle negative number in data stored in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, integer, hdfs, negative-number

I have an situation to handle negative numeric data. The position of the negative sign for some of the numeric values in the files (Stored in HDFS) are on the right side (like this 12345-), ideally negative number are denoted as minus in the left (like this, -12345).

I cannot change the data because this data is correct and when the data is used by the source system (SAP) it is able to read the data as negative number.

In hive I have to run some arithmetic manipulation, say I want SUM  this values which contains data like '12345-', then HIVE is unable to recognize this value as number (the column type is DECIMAL(10,2)) and the result shows NULL as value ! Need your kind advice how to handle this situation.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with changing your data type to `String`, then you will be able to use String functions on that ugly SAP format and produce something that you can `cast(... as decimal(10,2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check last character, if it is '-' then use substr and concat to construct correct value:

```
    select case when substr('12345-',-1,1)='-' then cast(concat('-',substr('12345-',1,length('12345-')-1)) as int) else cast('12345-' as int) end as column_name;
OK
-12345
```

Replace '12345-' with your column_name

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This did not work, the output still show NULL in Hive.

Comment: Debug it part by part. 1st check what `select substr(your_column,-1,1)` returns. 2nd: check `select cast(concat('-',substr(your_column,1,length(your_column)-1)) as int)` returns, 3rd: check the last `select cast(your_column as int)`. Maybe it cannot be converted to int (`cast function`) because there is non- int value, maybe double, or bigint or something else ?

Comment: @leftjoin: your approach would work **if** the original column was a String, but it has already been f... up as a Decimal *(read the question again)*. Hence the NULL. No way out of that mess, except changing the table definition first.

Comment: If course, I completely agree with you here. Need to change table definition first

Comment: Thank you, @leftjoin and @Samson! I am now able to handle the negative number in my hive query, your answer and reply have given me more light to a more complex issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```sql
CAST(CAST(-1 AS DECIMAL(1,0)) AS
 DECIMAL(10,2))*CAST(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(TRIM(column name),'\\-',''),'-','') as decimal(10,2)),
```